# Outlook 2007 To-do Bar on left?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a situation where a user, somehow, used to have their `Outlook 2007` `To-Do Bar` on the left hand side of Outlook vs the default right side.  He swears up and down that it is possible and absolutely refuses to let the issue die when I tell him that it is supposed to be on the right.

How can you move the to-do bar to the left side in Outlook 2007?

Comment: Everything that I have seen says it is not possible. I know that is not the answer that you were looking for, but that's all I could find.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm finding as well, but it was indeed like that and he's irate over it until I "fix" it...

Comment: How did he say that he got it to that state before? How did he "break" it?

Comment: He cannot explain how he did it, but this is a new system which is a migration from an old system that broke.

Comment: The last thing that I can think of is maybe he had an add-on, skin, or theme installed that somehow changed the location of the to-do bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Outlook 2010 while in calendar mode, you can use the view icons on the bottom toolbar next to the zoom bar on the right and select any view icon other than "classic".  At this point your calendars will show up on your left side navigation pane.  In the view tab you can also go to to-do bar and turn off date navigatior.  I can only get this to work in calendar view, not e-mail.